# Removing Trailing Zeros from Numeric Field in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.3, enterprise-geodatabase, fields-attributes

Working with a feature class in an enterprise GDB (SQL Server) which has a numeric field with type Double - precision 10, scale 3 - but is displaying trailing zeros on a lot of the values e.g. `265.360000`.

What can be done to remove the trailing zeros from the field?

**Edit:** The issue appears to only be in the *display* of the values within ArcMap and not how the values are being stored in the database.

Comment: You specified that you wanted 6 places to the right (10-3-1), and you got it.  If you defined the column "precision 6, scale 3" you'd get "265.36".  Trailing zeros don't use any storage -- why would they matter?

Comment: Simple answer is because they're harder to read.  You've lost me with your comment "you wanted 6 places to the right" - I want maximum of 3 decimal places, which is why I use scale of 3.

Comment: @Vince is saying "precision 10, scale 3" > 10-3-1 = 6 decimal places, "precision 6, scale 3" > 6-3-1 = 2 decimal places.  I haven't tested to verify that, but I trust his knowledge generally, and particularly in this area.  Also, where is it displaying the trailing zeros?  i.e. Attribute Table or elsewhere?

Comment: Yes in the attribute table.  According to Esri documentation `Scale` refers to number of decimal places, `Precision` is the max size of the field, so the way I read that is I can have a max of 10 digits, including 3 decimal places.  Shouldn't get to 6.

Comment: ArcSDE defines display in terms of "width" and "dec_digits". I've never seen "precision" and "scale" in reference to a table before, so I figured this was some weird Microsoft terminology, with a left side width.  It would help to edit the question to specify that you're referring to the table view in Desktop.

Comment: [Add Field Desktop Help](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/add-field.htm) says _The precision and scale of a field describe the maximum size and precision of data that can be stored in the field. The precision describes the number of digits that can be stored in the field and the **scale describes the number of decimal places** for float and double fields._   I didn't realise it was only a table display issue (and not a field value issue) until we really started digging.  I'll modify the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The specificity of the number of places can be set when you create the field. ESRI's help page provides this overview:

If you find that numeric values are being cut off or rounded in the table, right-click the field, click Properties, then review the number formatting. Since six is the default number of decimal places to display in the Table window, you may need to increase this value to see the full number.

**For example**, if you have a table in an ArcSDE geodatabase containing a field of type double with a scale of eight, the last two digits are dropped off because the Table window only displays six decimal places by default.

Increasing the number of decimal places will allow you to see all the digits. Similarly, you can decrease the number of decimal places if you want to see fewer in the Table window.

If you want to adjust your current table view to reduce the number of zeros after you have created it. Then you can use the python parser in the tables properties section, you can enter:

```
[Name].lstrip("0")
```

That should move any trailing zeros

Comment: Thanks @whyzar, that's where the issue was.  It was displaying extra zeros, not actually storing them.